# C# Windows Forms Data Binding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm using Visual c# in Windows forms and I'm very stuck.

```
myTxtBx.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", myBindingSource, "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, string.Empty));
```

My issue is that `myTxtBx` receives no updates at all; I actually changed it to a text box because it wouldn't work with a label either.

Within the code I am assigning myTxtBx a value, as this is how it has to be done in this situation.

I need a way that the bindings will take the value from the text box, despite not being updated at all.

I have tried changing it to `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation` and forcing it to validate before doing the DB stuff, but the DataBindings still didn't take the value.
I also tried using `WriteValue()` and that didn't seem to work either..

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the nature of `myBindingSource`?

Comment: It's holds a dataset. I know that this works in a way as i have used this code in other places (but with updating controls).. It's specifically where the text box is receiving no update which is causing the issue.. the binding assumes that it is null

Comment: Literally a `DataSet`?  Then how will your binding know which of the included `DataTable` to bind `Name` to?  Typically the binding source is a table, not the whole collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checked your issue on sample.
I have `Form` with two `TextBox`, bindings looks like:

```
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.bindingSource1, "Text", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
this.textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.bindingSource1, "Text", true));
```

Binding source `this.bindingSource1` is type of `System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource`

Here is the code of setting binding source data:

```
_bindedObject = new DataObject{ Text = "Initialized value"};
bindingSource1.DataSource = _bindedObject;
```

An the `_bindedObject` is simple class with property Text:

```
[Serializable]
public class DataObject
{
    public string Text { get; set; } 
}
```

`textBox1` keeps updating data on every change of containing text and `textBox2` is refreshing.
`textBox2` is updating data when it lose focus (causes validation) or when the `bindingSource1.EndEdit();` is called.

Comment: This seems a little long winded, I'm surprised that there isn't something which is built in to do this.. Thanks :)